# Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization in pure Tensorflow: performance for iterative solution is much slower than numpy

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I want to do Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization to fix big matrices which start to deviate slightly from orthogonality in pure Tensorflow (to do it on the graph within larger computation, without breaking it). The solutions I've seen [like the one there](https://github.com/EigenPro/EigenPro-tensorflow/blob/master/utils.py) are used "externally" (doing multiple `sess.run` inside).

So I wrote a simple and I think very inefficient implementation myself:

```
def tf_gram_schmidt(vectors):
    # add batch dimension for matmul
    basis = tf.expand_dims(vectors[0,:]/tf.norm(vectors[0,:]),0)
    for i in range(1,vectors.get_shape()[0].value):
        v = vectors[i,:]
        # add batch dimension for matmul
        v = tf.expand_dims(v,0) 
        w = v - tf.matmul(tf.matmul(v, tf.transpose(basis)), basis)
         # I assume that my matrix is close to orthogonal
        basis = tf.concat([basis, w/tf.norm(w)],axis=0)
    return basis
```

But when I compare it with the same iterative external code, it is 3 times slower (on GPU !!!) (though has a bit better precision):

```
how much source differs from orthogonal matrix:
44.7176
tensorflow version:
0.034667
Time elapsed: 23365.9820557ms
numpy version with tensorflow and variable re-assign to the result of numpy code:
0.057589
Time elapsed: 8540.5600071ms
```

(UPD 4: I had a small mistake in my example, but it didn't change timings at all, as `ort_discrepancy()` is a lightweight function):

Minimal example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

import numpy as np

import time

# found this code somewhere on stackoverflow
def np_gram_schmidt(vectors):
    basis = []
    for v in vectors:
        w = v - np.sum( np.dot(v,b)*b  for b in basis )
        if (w > 1e-10).any():  
            basis.append(w/np.linalg.norm(w))
        else:
            basis.append(np.zeros(w.shape))
    return np.array(basis)



def tf_gram_schmidt(vectors):
    # add batch dimension for matmul
    basis = tf.expand_dims(vectors[0,:]/tf.norm(vectors[0,:]),0)
    for i in range(1,vectors.get_shape()[0].value):
        v = vectors[i,:]
        # add batch dimension for matmul
        v = tf.expand_dims(v,0) 
        w = v - tf.matmul(tf.matmul(v, tf.transpose(basis)), basis)
         # I assume that my matrix is close to orthogonal
        basis = tf.concat([basis, w/tf.norm(w)],axis=0)
    return basis





# how much matrix differs from orthogonal
# computes ||W*W^T - I||2
def ort_discrepancy(matrix):    
    wwt = tf.matmul(matrix, matrix, transpose_a=True)
    rows = tf.shape(wwt)[0]
    cols = tf.shape(wwt)[1]    
    return tf.norm((wwt - tf.eye(rows,cols)),ord='euclidean') 


np.random.seed(0)
# white noise matrix
np_nearly_orthogonal = np.random.normal(size=(2000,2000)) 
# centered rows
np_nearly_orthogonal = np.array([row/np.linalg.norm(row) for row in np_nearly_orthogonal]) 


tf_nearly_orthogonal = tf.Variable(np_nearly_orthogonal,dtype=tf.float32)


init = tf.global_variables_initializer()



with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    print("how much source differs from orthogonal matrix:")
    print(ort_discrepancy(tf_nearly_orthogonal).eval())

    print("tensorflow version:")
    start = time.time()

    print(ort_discrepancy(tf_gram_schmidt(tf_nearly_orthogonal)).eval())

    end = time.time()
    print("Time elapsed: %sms"%(1000*(end-start)))

    print("numpy version with tensorflow and variable re-assign to the result of numpy code:")
    start = time.time()

    tf_nearly_orthogonal = tf.Variable(np_gram_schmidt(tf_nearly_orthogonal.eval()),dtype=tf.float32)
    sess.run(tf.variables_initializer([tf_nearly_orthogonal]))



    # check that variable was updated
    print(ort_discrepancy(tf_nearly_orthogonal).eval())
    end = time.time()
    print("Time elapsed: %sms"%(1000*(end-start)))
```

Is there a way to speed it up? I couldn't figure out how to do it for G-S which requires appending to the basis (so no `tf.map_fn` parallelization can help).

UPD: I have achieved difference in 2x by optimizing `tf.matmul`:

```
def tf_gram_schmidt(vectors):
    # add batch dimension for matmul
    basis = tf.expand_dims(vectors[0,:]/tf.norm(vectors[0,:]),0)
    for i in range(1,vectors.get_shape()[0].value):
        v = vectors[i,:]
        # add batch dimension for matmul
        v = tf.expand_dims(v,0) 
        w = v - tf.matmul(tf.matmul(v, basis, transpose_b=True), basis)
         # I assume that my matrix is close to orthogonal
        basis = tf.concat([basis, w/tf.norm(w)],axis=0)
    return basis





how much source differs from orthogonal matrix:
44.7176
tensorflow version:
0.0335421
Time elapsed: 17004.458189ms
numpy version with tensorflow and variable re-assign to the result of numpy code:
0.057589
Time elapsed: 8082.20791817ms
```

EDIT2:

Just for fun, tried to fully mimic numpy solution, and got extremely long working code:

```
def tf_gram_schmidt(vectors):
    # add batch dimension for matmul
    basis = tf.expand_dims(vectors[0,:]/tf.norm(vectors[0,:]),0)
    for i in range(1,vectors.get_shape()[0].value):

        v = vectors[i,:]        
        # like in numpy example
        multiplied = tf.reduce_sum(tf.map_fn(lambda b: tf.scalar_mul(tf.tensordot(v,b,axes=[[0],[0]]),b), basis), axis=0)
        w = v - multiplied    



        ## add batch dimension for matmul
        ##v = tf.expand_dims(v,0) 
        ##w = v - tf.matmul(tf.matmul(v, basis, transpose_b=True), basis) 

        # I assume that my matrix is close to orthogonal
        basis = tf.concat([basis, tf.expand_dims(w/tf.norm(w),0)],axis=0)
    return basis
```

(which seems to overfill GPU memory as well):

```
how much source differs from orthogonal matrix:
44.7176
tensorflow version:
2018-01-05 22:12:09.854505: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:247] PoolAllocator: After 14005 get requests, put_count=5105 evicted_count=1000 eviction_rate=0.195886 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.714031
2018-01-05 22:12:09.854530: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:259] Raising pool_size_limit_ from 100 to 110
2018-01-05 22:12:13.090296: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:247] PoolAllocator: After 308520 get requests, put_count=314261 evicted_count=6000 eviction_rate=0.0190924 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.00088487
2018-01-05 22:12:22.270822: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:247] PoolAllocator: After 1485113 get requests, put_count=1500399 evicted_count=16000 eviction_rate=0.0106638 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.000490198
2018-01-05 22:12:37.833056: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:247] PoolAllocator: After 3484575 get requests, put_count=3509407 evicted_count=26000 eviction_rate=0.00740866 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.000339209
2018-01-05 22:12:59.995184: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:247] PoolAllocator: After 6315546 get requests, put_count=6349923 evicted_count=36000 eviction_rate=0.00566936 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.000259202
0.0290728
Time elapsed: 136108.97398ms
numpy version with tensorflow and variable re-assign to the result of numpy code:
0.057589
Time elapsed: 10618.8428402ms
```

UPD3: My GPU is GTX1050, it usually has speedup 5-7 times in comparison to my CPU. So the result is very strange for me.

UPD5: Ok, I found that GPU is almost not used for this code, while training neural network with manually written backpropagation which uses a lot of `tf.matmul`'s and other matrix arithmetics fully exploits it. Why is it so?

---

UPD 6:

Following the given suggestion I have measured the time in a new way:

```
# Akshay's suggestion to measure performance correclty
orthogonalized = ort_discrepancy(tf_gram_schmidt(tf_nearly_orthogonal))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    print("how much source differs from orthogonal matrix:")
    print(ort_discrepancy(tf_nearly_orthogonal).eval())

    print("tensorflow version:")
    start = time.time()

    tf_result = sess.run(orthogonalized)

    end = time.time()

    print(tf_result)

    print("Time elapsed: %sms"%(1000*(end-start)))

    print("numpy version with tensorflow and variable re-assign to the result of numpy code:")
    start = time.time()

    tf_nearly_orthogonal = tf.Variable(np_gram_schmidt(tf_nearly_orthogonal.eval()),dtype=tf.float32)
    sess.run(tf.variables_initializer([tf_nearly_orthogonal]))



    # check that variable was updated
    print(ort_discrepancy(tf_nearly_orthogonal).eval())

    end = time.time()
    print("Time elapsed: %sms"%(1000*(end-start)))
```

Now I can see 4x speedup:

```
how much source differs from orthogonal matrix:
44.7176
tensorflow version:
0.018951
Time elapsed: 2594.85888481ms
numpy version with tensorflow and variable re-assign to the result of numpy code:
0.057589
Time elapsed: 8851.86600685ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlow appears slow because your benchmark is measuring both the time that it construct the graph and the time it takes to execute it; a fairer comparison between TensorFlow and NumPy would exclude graph construction from the benchmark. In particular, your benchmark should probably look something like this:

```
print("tensorflow version:")
# This line constructs the graph but does not execute it.
orthogonalized = ort_discrepancy(tf_gram_schmidt(tf_nearly_orthogonal))

start = time.time()
tf_result = sess.run(orthogonalized)
end = time.time()
```

Comment: Thanks very much !! Now I have re-measured the time and see 4x speedup (see last update)

Comment: I have also measured the time within Numpy function, and it takes 7sec to process, so pure tensorflow is 7/2.6 = 2.7 times faster. Not very good, I must say, I think it might be possible to optimize; but at least now I can do orthogonalization without breaking my code.